# Function ignoring first function in range

Tags: scheme

So in my function, I need to square all the numbers from the range a to b.

This is my code:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (consecutive-squares a b)
  (if (> a b)
      '()
      (map square (consecutive-ints(+ a 1)b))))
```

When running the test of `(consecutive-squares 1 10)` it outputs `(4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100)` it is completely missing the first number in the range `1`. Which is needed to pass the example tests

Comment: Are you not skipping `1` deliberately with passing `(+ a 1)`?

Comment: @Sylwester yes that is what I was thinking, I am just not sure how else to move through the range without adding (+ a 1)

Comment: `consecutive-ints` moves through the range that it's given, why do you think you need to add 1 when calling it?

Comment: I'd also expect it to return an empty list when the start is greater than the end, so you don't need that check in `consecutive-squares`.

Comment: Move through? Haven't you tested it by calling `(consecutive-ints 1 10)` and `(consecutive-ints 2 10)`?

Comment: ah yes, you guys were right, its just the first time I removed the add 1 it gave me an error now it is giving me the correct answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `consecutive-ints` function knows how to add 1 to each value to get the next one in the range, you don't need to do that when calling it. I'd also expect it to handle an empty range, so you don't need your own check for that.

```
(define (consecutive-squares a b)
  (map square (consecutive-ints a b))
```